# JS statement question: replacementory for 'return' in 'for loop' to get all values from 'for loop'

Tags: javascript, return, closures

Because of return itself, `numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder;` gives only one value, "1 : a" on console.

But I want

"1 : a

2 : b

3 : c

4 : d

5 : e

6 : f"

on console.log.

Plus, I do not want `consol.log(numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder);` instead of `return numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder;`, because `consol.log(numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder);` print

"1 : a

2 : b

3 : c

4 : d

5 : e

6 : f

undefined"

To prevent printing `undefined` at the end of the `numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder;`, how can I improve this code?

```js
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];


function x() {
  for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    var numInOrder = i+1;
    var nameInOrder = list[i];
    
    return numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder;
  }
}

console.log(x());
```

Answer (score 0):

Map to an array of strings you want, then join that array by `\n` and return it:

```js
list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
const x = () => list
  .map((char, i) => char + ' : ' + (i + 1))
  .join('\n');

console.log(x());
```

Or, to change your original code, less concisely, but with the same logic:

```js
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

function x() {
  const arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var numInOrder = i + 1;
    var nameInOrder = list[i];

    arr.push(numInOrder + " : " + nameInOrder);
  }
  return arr.join('\n');
}

console.log(x());
```

Comment: Second one is what I've been looking for. Thanks for your help

Comment: It works, but array methods are much more concise and functional - once you can get used to them, they'll make your code look a whole lot cleaner

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you may consider upvoting and/or marking it as Accepted (check the checkbox on the left) to indicate that the issue is resolved :)